# Real Integral calculation through complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am stuck with this integral, that I must solve with a complex one. First I thought it would get easier, as a polynomial in the denominator and I would get the old and good residue times $2\pi i$  but it didn't get and I refuse to invert the obtained series. Is there any other way.

What I've done so far.
$$  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\left( 3+2sin(t)\right )^2}dt$$
$$\oint \frac{1}{\left( 9+12\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}+4(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i})^2  \right )}\frac{dz}{iz} $$
$$ \oint \frac{1}{\left(7iz+6iz^2-6+iz^3+iz^{-1} \right )}dz$$

Should I invert this series, or try to find the roots modifying the denominator, I think I am missing something at plain sight.

Comment: Now you use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and the fact that the integrand is a rational function.

Comment: i have corrected the third integral form. I know I must use the residue theorem, but I do not know how to expand that rational function to its Laurent series.

Comment: Should i find the zeros of $7iz^2+6iz^3+iz^4+i$ or is there an easier way than computing all those roots?

Comment: You need to find them to know which one of them are in your contour

Comment: You don't need Laurent series. The roots of the denominator don't seem to be pretty. But notice that you only need the residues for the poles that are inside the unit circle. You can show that the real roots are outside the unit circle, for example by bounding from above the roots of $7z^2+6z+1+z^4$, which are the reciprocals of your polynomial. Therefore, the roots that you care about are not real. Since the coefficients are real, those two roots are conjugate of each other.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be much les than computing all those roots. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I thought it would be much les than computing all those roots. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why expand the square at all? If the goal is to find the zeroes, stay with $$(3+2\sin t)^2=(3-i(z-z^{-1}))^2=-z^{-2}(z^2-3iz-1)^2$$

Comment: you are right dude, I mean Did (hehe?). Thanks a lot, thats what i wasn't seeing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac {1}{(3 + 2\frac {e^{it} - e^{-it}}{2i})^2}\ dt\\
z = e^{it}\\
dz = i e^{it} dt\\
-iz^{-1} dz = dt$

$\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac {-iz^{-1}}{(3 -iz + iz^{-1})^2} \ dz$

multiply numerator and denominator by $(iz)^2$

$\oint \frac {iz}{(3iz + z^2 - 1)^2} \ dz\\
\oint \frac {iz}{(z-a)^2(z-b)^2} \ dz$

There is one pole inside the contour and it is of order 2.

$\oint \frac {f(z)}{(z-a)^2} = 2\pi i f'(a)$

$f(z) =  \frac {iz}{(z -b)^2}\\ 
f'(z) = \frac {-i(z + b)}{(z-b)^3}\\
f'(a) = \frac {-i(a+b)}{(a-b)^3}$

$a = -\frac {3 - \sqrt 5}{2}i\\ 
b = -\frac {3 + \sqrt 5}{2}i\\
a+b = 3i\\
a-b = -\sqrt 5i\\
2\pi i f'(a) = \frac {6\pi}{5\sqrt5}$